# Can't calculate the difference between two dates using datetime

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I was trying to caltculate the date using datetime module, but when I entered `1` in define `dates` it showed me:

```
41 days, 0:00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 22, in <module>
    print(dates(i))
          ^^^^^^^^
  File "", line 18, in dates
    SD = date(YY2, MM2, DD2)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Strangely, when i entered `0` in define it gave me a nice result, unlike `1`. Dates were taken from the txt file.

```
from datetime import *

f = open('a0.txt')
n = f.readlines()

def dates(j):
    l = n[j]
    nl = list(l)
    nl.remove('\n')
    nl.remove('\t') #these were used because origianal txt file inlcuded tabulation
    DD1 = int(nl[0] + nl[1])
    MM1 = int(nl[3] + nl[4])
    YY1 = int(nl[6] + nl[7] + nl[8] + nl[9])
    DD2 = int(nl[10] + nl[10])
    MM2 = int(nl[13] + nl[14])
    YY2 = int(nl[16] + nl[17] + nl[18] + nl[19]) #day, month, year for each date
    FD = date(YY1, MM1, DD1)
    SD = date(YY2, MM2, DD2)
    delta = abs(SD - FD) #difference
    return delta
for i in range(len(n)): #difference for each line of dates
    print(dates(i))
```

[*That one txt file*](https://pastebin.com/iimJhgC9)

Comment: This table looks nice, but it's not an accurate representation of the file contents.  It doesn't tell us anything about spacing or separator characters.  Please show us the **actual** file contents.

Comment: FYI Use `strptime` to parse dates instead of manually

Comment: This code works (after correcting the typo), but would splitting the line into two date (using `l.split('\t')`), and then splitting the date into 3 parts using `(l.split('\t')[0]).split('.')` not be easier?

Answer (score 1):

On that loop iteration, the code is trying to use 0 for the day:

```
date(2024,3,0)
```

This is because you have an incorrect calculation for the day:

```
DD2 = int(nl[10] + nl[10])
```

You're adding `nl[10]` twice, but you meant to use `nl[10] + nl[11]`.